# Merge more than 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have 23 dataframes that I need to merge. I have read that you can merge them by putting them into a list. All of the sheets have the same column names but somewhat different rows. I would like to merge them on the column 'RowNo'. Not all the rows in the sheets will merge on 'RowNo' though. I would like the leftover rows to be included in the merge as well. I believe this is called an outer join.

Example of df:

```
Row No   Horse    Weight
112               55
115      Winx
```

Example of another df

```
Row No   Horse    Weight
112      Black    
115      Winx     54
117      Pharlap  51
```

Desired output:

```
 Row No   Horse    Weight
 112      Black    55
 115      Winx     54
 117      Pharlap  51
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce


dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, ...]
df_final = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on="RowNo"), dfs)
```